# Graph of this function

Tags: graphing-functions, function-and-relation-composition

Let f is a real valued function defined from R to R such that f(x)+f(-x)=5

---

Is this function even , can we plot this function ‘f’ on graph?
And what information do we get from this functional equation?

Comment: Many such functions are possible $f(x)=2.5$ or $f(x)=x+2.5$. As you can see with the latter example it need not be even. Define $f$ for $x \geq 0$ first and then define $f$ for $x<0$ as $-f(x)+5$ (with $x>0$).

Comment: @AnuragA is this function even

Answer (score 0):

Here are two examples, $x^2$ and $x^3$ for $x \geq 0$:

[image]